# How to generate swagger document for functional variant of webflux

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux

How to generate swagger documents for functional variant of Webflux
which defines routes like

```
RouterFunctions.route(POST("/createEmployee")...).andRoute(GET("/getAllEmployee")...)
```

I have tried the `Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE` and `Springfox 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. But it doesn't recognize the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not supported yet. See https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2632

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now is possible, take a look on this https://springdoc.org/